# How to extract strings using Regex in pandas based on multiple if-conditions

Tags: python, regex, pandas, if-statement

```py
dframe = pd.DataFrame({'Num':['38-30','38-30','21-51','24-11','34-20'],
'Des':['Generates Vacuum','Pressure low','Ground Problem',
'Leak from Controller','Lock Unserviceable']})
```

In the above dataframe I want to extract specific strings from `Des` column based on the `Num` column. For instance, if `Num` is equal to `38-30` then extract `Vacuum` from `Des` and if it doesn't have `Vacuum`, then extract `Pressure`. There are multiple strings that I have to extract for each `Num`.

I am trying to use `re.extract('generator|Pressure',re.I)` but I don't know how to include the `if` statements as I mentioned above.

My output should look like this:
[image]

Comment: kindly post ur expected output

Comment: I've aded the expected output. Thank you!

Comment: Seems u hav multiple conditions as evidenced from ur output

Comment: Yes. Is there a way that I can achieve that with Regex and If conditions?

Comment: @YOBEN's answer below involves regex and a vectorized IF statement

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where` with `findall`

```
np.where(df.Num.eq('38-30'),df.Des.str.findall('generator|vacuum',flags=re.IGNORECASE),'')
```